# Nested Routing isn't working with react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I try to understand the nested routing in react using react-router-dom. I was simply following their offical [docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start). Where The route `/users` loads the Users component, which renders any further `<Route>`'s conditionally on the paths :id value. [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-elgamal-dzd0s?file=/src/users.js) is the codesandbox link. But whenever I goto `users/:id`, it render the fallback component. I was wondering where I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the exact value here:

```
<Route exact path="/users" component={Users} />
```

if you use exact only that EXACT path will be usable
so /users is fine but /users/1 is not

Comment: Thanks @istvan Kolkert I feel shame seriously I failed to catch this. I will accept your answer after 7 min.

Comment: @falamiw Haha no worries, everyone overlooks things no shame in asking